# Extracting city,province, country etc from address in SSIS

Tags: ssis, substring, extract

I am doing ETL and want to extract city, province from 1000s of addresses. I have tried `SUBSTRING( «character_expression», «start», «length» )` transformation in SSIS but could not get the result becuase I don't know in each address, where is the start of substring and what is length of each required substring.

Following are the examples from which I want "M.D.A. ROAD" , "MULTAN" etc.

```
PAKISTAN COTTON GINNERS' ASSOCIATION PCGA HOUSE, M.D.A. ROAD, MULTAN
PAKISTAN CROP PROTECTION ASSOCIATION 2-A, INDUSTRIAL ESTATE ROOMY COTTON FACTORY, MULTAN
PAKISTAN AGRICULTURE & DAIRY FARMERS ASSOCIATION 16-C, PEOPLES COLONY, FAISALABAD
THE FAISALABAD CHAMBER OF COMMERCE & INDUSTRY FCCI COMPLEX, EAST, CANAL ROAD, FAISALABAD
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will you identify `city` or `Province` from the given address ? Do you have a `master table` for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two strategies that you could use, depending whether the address structure is regular or not

1. Use the location of the `,` characters to break up the address into components
2. Use a lookup table of known streets and provinces to identify them in the address

Option 1 is the simplest - but relies on the address format being consistent: i.e. all components are separated by a `,`, province is always the last component, city is always the second last.

You'd use the `TOKEN` function to break the address up by `,`

For province (the last component) it would be something like:

```
TRIM(TOKEN([Address], ",", TOKENCOUNT([Address], ",")))
```

For city (the second last component), it would be:

```
TRIM(TOKEN([Address], ",", TOKENCOUNT([Address], ",") - 1))
```

Comment: Ross McNab Thanks for reply but I am using SSIS 2008 and TOKEN function is not available in this version. How can I do this in SSIS 2008 ?